# Getting score with payload in Solr

Tags: java, solr, lucene, payload

I'm a newbie with Solr and I'm trying to retrieve documents like this, sorted by the payload.

```
{ "id": "1", "tags": ["Cat|0.8", "Dog|0.2"] },
{ "id": "2", "tags": ["Cat|0.4", "Dog|0.6"] }
```

I'm trying to use a payload to boost each tag, but all info I found it's a bit old. [This](https://lucidworks.com/2014/06/13/end-to-end-payload-example-in-solr/) is the most recent publication I've found.

But I've found [this, too](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/payloads/DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory.html) and I don't know if there is anything newer than the first method. With the second link I think I can add to schema.xml

```
 <fieldType name="tags" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>
     <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory" encoder="float" delimiter="|"/>
   </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```

And the payload would be recognized. But I don't know how to check that, I only see that searching for "Dog" the result is not sorted by the payload.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"Dog",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1493191003038"}},
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"1",
        "tags":["Cat|0.8",
          "Dog|0.2"],
        "_version_":1565724328306147328},
      {
        "id":"2",
        "tags":["Cat|0.4",
          "Dog|0.6"],
        "_version_":1565724328307195904}]
  }}
```

So I don't know what to do... Should I follow the first tutorial even I have the newest Solr version? My aim is simple: sort the response by the payload in the tag.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49195384/2709131

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the possible values or tags are limited (not more than thousands), IMHO the easiest path for you would be:

1. massage the data into some format that is easier to use by Solr, for example:

   ```
   { "id": "1", "tags": ["Cat", "Dog"], "tag_Cat": "0.8", "tag_Dog":"0.2"}
   ```
2. for the tag_ type fields, you could define a dynamicField tag_* that will cover all the possibilities, and index it into a tfloat (also with docValues probably)
3. now you can easily sort (or boost) by the relevant field (tag_Cat...) every time you need.